# How to work around ASN.1 library not supporting RELATIVE-OID

Tags: python, asn.1, pyasn1, asn1tools

I’m trying to use the [`asn1tools`](https://pypi.org/project/asn1tools/) Python library to decode and encode BER messages conforming to the [Ember+](https://github.com/Lawo/ember-plus) standard.

[That standard’s DTD](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scy/ember-plus/fix-dtd-syntax/EmberLib.net/EmberLib.Glow/Documentation/GlowDtd.asn1) uses ASN.1’s `RELATIVE-OID` type in some places. However, `asn1tools` doesn’t know about this type, probably because the underlying `pyasn1` library doesn’t implement it (not yet, there’s [a pull request](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1/pull/196)). Which is why I can’t use that DTD in my Python program. But I really have to.

My options, as I see them, are to either create a patched version of `pyasn1` with the `RELATIVE-OID` PR included and make `asn1tools` work with it, or to somehow build a workaround in the DTD.

I’ve already tried adding `RELATIVE-OID ::= [UNIVERSAL 13] OCTET STRING` to the DTD, but now `asn1tools` responds with `Expected RELATIVE-OID with tag '2d' at offset 10, but got '0d'.` Basically it seems to accept my definition, but makes it “universal constructed 13” while the message tags it as “universal **primitive** 13”.

Is there a way for me to work around this?

Here are my constraints:

- I basically *have* to use `asn1tools`, my code is already heavily depending on it.
- I *have* to be able to parse and create messages compatible to other third-party clients that tag these fields as `0d`.
- I *can* edit around in the DTD as I please, for example adding a type that defines `RELATIVE-OID` (but in what way?) or replacing every occurrence of `RELATIVE-OID` with something else, as long as it will still work with the messages that tag the fields as `0d`.
- I’m totally okay with getting the `RELATIVE-OID` value as an opaque blob of `bytes` or something, which is why I’ve tried the `OCTET STRING` workaround in the first place.

My ASN.1 knowledge is limited and I’m not proficient in writing DTDs. Maybe there’s a way to force the type to being “primitive”? I’m happy for any suggestions. If you’d like to try it out for yourself, use the DTD linked above. Then, use the following Python code:

```py
import asn1tools

spec = asn1tools.compile_files('GlowDtd.asn1')

print(spec.decode('Root', b'`\x80k\x80\xa0\x80b\x80\xa0\x03\x02\x01 \xa1\x03\x02\x01\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
# should result in ('elements', [('element', ('command', {'number': 32, 'options': ('dirFieldMask', -1)}))])

print(spec.decode('Root', b'`\x80k\x80\xa0\x80j\x80\xa0\x03\r\x01\x01\xa2\x80d\x80\xa0\x80b\x80\xa0\x03\x02\x01 \xa1\x03\x02\x01\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
# doesn't work because it uses RELATIVE-OID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RELATIVE-OID ::= [UNIVERSAL 13] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING
```